$(\lambda I-A)^{-1}-(\lambda I-B)^{-1}$ compact implies $\sigma_\text{ess}(A)=\sigma_\text{ess}(B)$
Suppose $H$ is a Hilbert space and $A$, $B$ are two adjoint operators on it (not necessarily bounded), satisfying $D(A)=D(B)$.

Question: If $\exists \lambda\in \rho(A)\cap\rho(B)$ such that $(\lambda I-A)^{-1}-(\lambda I-B)^{-1}$ is compact, how to show $\sigma_\text{ess}(A)=\sigma_\text{ess}(B)$?

Of course $(\lambda I-A)^{-1}-(\lambda I-B)^{-1}=(\lambda I-A)^{-1}(A-B)(\lambda I-B)^{-1}$. But since $A$, $B$ are not bounded, I don't know how to show $A-B$ is compact with respect to $A$ (hence Weyl's theorem can not be applied here).
Could you provide some help? Thanks.

The operators $(\lambda I - A)^{-1}$ and $(\lambda I - B)^{-1}$ have the same essential spectrum since their difference is compact. Now one can use that the essential spectrum satisfies the spectral mapping theorem for the resolvent.
